# Permanent way to keep youtube playing in iOS5

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube

Is there a permanent way to keep youtube playing when I tap the home button or close the lid of my iPad? I know that if I double click on the home button, slide to the bottom list of apps to the right and press play, it keeps youtube playing. But I do not want to mess with it everytime. So, do you know a way to keep youtube playing without doing this everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different app for playing Youtube videos, which don't stop playing when you press the home button. [YStream](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ystream-youtube-edition/id384383425?mt=8)/[Ystream2](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ystream2-youtube-edition/id555287565?mt=8) is an example of such an application (amongst others).

As far as I know there is no way to prevent the built in Youtube app from stopping playback when the app is "minimized". These are the ways I know of for resuming playback:

- Double tap the Home button, slide the bottom row, and press play. (As you mentioned)
- Lock the screen, Double tap Home button, Press Play. (I usually find this slightly faster)
- Use a Bluetooth keybord with a "Play" button.
- Activating VoiceOver and double tapping the screen with two fingers.
- Using the Play button on your headphones.